# Copying values into Nan fields

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large data-frame with the format as below:

[image]

If any of the cell is "NaN", i want to copy from the cell immediately above it. So, my dataframe should look like:

[image]

In case the first row has "NaN", then I'll have to let it be.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: is this `pandas`? if so you just need to call `ffill`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like `pandas` if so you need to call `ffill`

```
In [72]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['A0','A1','A2',np.NaN,np.NaN, 'A3'], 'B':['B0','B1','B2',np.NaN,np.NaN, 'B3'], 'C':['C0','C1','C2',np.NaN,np.NaN, 'C3']})
df

Out[72]:
     A    B    C
0   A0   B0   C0
1   A1   B1   C1
2   A2   B2   C2
3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   A3   B3   C3

In [73]:    
df.ffill()

Out[73]:
    A   B   C
0  A0  B0  C0
1  A1  B1  C1
2  A2  B2  C2
3  A2  B2  C2
4  A2  B2  C2
5  A3  B3  C3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for help !

Comment: New here...Didn't know how to accept the answer, took me a while to figure out... ;-)

Comment: No worries, I think the reason this was downvoted is that you didn't provide sample data, code, any errors and what the desired output should be in text form. Posting images isn't helpful as people can't copy/paste code in images, it maybe worth reading this http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve